# How to add classes sequentially to elements without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I did a bit of searching but could only find jQuery examples.

I’ve got a user input to take a number, the number will correlate to how many elements are shown. I’m trying to run a function that will add the `shown` class to the correct amount of elements.

The template section is showing but the classes aren’t being added to the articles. I’m not getting any errors in Firebug. What am I doing wrong?

If there’s a better way to achieve this please let me know.

No jQuery please.

I’m just looking to add a class sequentially to each article element depending on the value of the `bannerCount` input.

```js
var numBanners = document.getElementById('bannerCount').value;
var template = 1;
var template1 = document.getElementById('template1');
var template2 = document.getElementById('template2');

function genTemplate() {
  if (template == 1) {
    template2.className = "hide";
    template1.className = "show";
    for (var i = 0; i < numBanners; i++) {
      var q = document.querySelector('#template1:nth-child(i)');
      q.className = "show";
    }
  } else if (template == 2) {
    template1.className = "hide";
    template2.className = "show";
    for (var i = 0; i < numBanners; i++) {
      var q = document.querySelector('#template2:nth-child(i)');
      q.className = "show";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="bannerCount" value="1" min="1" max="10" name="bannerCount">

<input type="button" name="genTemplate" id="genTemplate" onClick="genTemplate();" value="Generate templates">

<section id="template1" class="hide">
  <article id="t11" class="t1"></article>
  <article id="t12" class="t1"></article>
  <article id="t13" class="t1"></article>
  <article id="t14" class="t1"></article>
</section>
<section id="template2" class="hide">
  <article id="t21" class="t2"></article>
  <article id="t22" class="t2"></article>
  <article id="t23" class="t2"></article>
  <article id="t24" class="t2"></article>
</section>
```

Comment: 1. The selector `#template1:nth-child(i)` is not a valid selector. Are you sure you're not getting an error? 2. The selector `#template1:nth-child(2)` selects the element with id `template1` **who is the second child of its parent**; it does not select the second child of the element with id `template1`.

Comment: So how would I be able to select each child sequentially and add the class to each one until it reaches the limit?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to search the DOM in every iteration, when you could loop over a collection of elements retrieved once. Also note that `i` in your selectors is hard coded into the string...it's not a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'#template1:nth-child(i)'
```

I think you wanted

```
'#template1 > *:nth-child('+i+')'
```

Although, like the commenters say, that code is pretty silly and you should probably just loop through `template1.children`

```
for(var i=0; i<numBanners; i++) {
  template1.children[i].className = "show"
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just didn't know a better way, looping through the children looks good. I've changed it to this and it's working perfectly -  `for(var i = 0; i < numBanners; i++) {
  var q = template1.children;
  q[i].className = "show";
  }`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var pre = onload;
function onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function T(e, t){
  return e.getElementsByTagName(t);
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function inArray(v, a){
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a[i] === v){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function removeClass(c, e){
  var x = c.split(/\s/), s = e.className.split(/\s/), r = [];
  for(var i=0,l=s.length; i<l; i++){
     if(!inArray(s[i], x))r.push(s[i]);
  }
  e.className = r.join(' ');
}
function addClass(c, e){
  var s = e.className.split(/\s/);
  if(!inArray(c, s)){
    s.push(c); e.className = s.join(' ');
  }
}
function showArticles(secId, num){
  var aa = T(E(secId), 'article');
  for(var i=0,l=aa.length; i<l; i++){
    var a = aa[i];
    removeClass('show', a); addClass('hide', a);
  }
  for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
    var a = aa[i];
    removeClass('hide', a) addClass('show' a);
  }
}
showArticles('template1', 2);
}
```